# SwiftUI - @Published property is not updating view from coordinator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using a wrapper around `UISearchBar` and I'm seeing a different behavior when passing a `@Published` property into this `SearchBar` wrapper versus a `TextField`.

Both are updating the `@ObservedObject var query = Query()` class `@Published var input` property as expected but only the `TextField` is then updating the `SearchSheet` view. I would like for the view to be updated when `input` has been changed in `SearchBar` similarly to how it is updated from `TextField`.

Edit: I've updated my question to include the `ContentView` where it looks like this issue is specific to when the sheet is called from a `Button` in a `NavigationBarItem`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSearch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingSearch.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingSearch) {
                    SearchSheet(isPresented: self.$showingSearch)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Query: ObservableObject {
    @Published var input = "" {
        didSet {
            // Called as expected in both cases but only TextField updates the SearchSheet view.
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SearchSheet: View {
    @ObservedObject var query = Query()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Does not update the SearchSheet view. I would like it understand why and how to update it.
            SearchBar(text: $query.input, placeholder: "Search")
            // Does update the SearchSheet view.
            TextField("Search", text: $query.input)

            Text("\(query.input)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}

struct SearchBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var text = ""
    
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchBar(text: $text, placeholder: "Search")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine as-is with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: Thank you @Asperi, you're correct that in a new project this does seem to work as expected. I've updated to include the ContentView which is making this fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the display of the sheet out from `navigationBarItems` resolves the issue. At the time I believe this is a bug.

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    Button(action: {
        self.showingSearch.toggle()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
    }
)
.sheet(isPresented: $showingSearch) {
    SearchSheet(isPresented: self.$showingSearch)
}
```